# The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process” Windows Application Development

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows

I have seen similar questions however the answers didn't help me out. I am coding a basic windows application using c#. This is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Practice
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void label4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        this.Hide();
        Main main = new Main();
        main.Show();

    }

    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
}
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Main is a second window that is opened.

The other methods are there because I would have double clicked by mistake.

Comment: Where are you seeing this error?

Comment: When I build the solution I get the following in the error list:

Comment: Unable to copy file "obj\Debug\Practice.exe" to "bin\Debug\Practice.exe". The process cannot access the file 'bin\Debug\Practice.exe' because it is being used by another process. Practice

Comment: Sounds like your application is still running. Start task manager, find it and kill it :)

Comment: This sometimes happens if you have disabled the `Application Experience` windows service  (`Task Manager` -> `Services` -> `AeLookupSvc`).   Is this service running?     https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/902196/description-of-the-application-experience-lookup-service-in-windows-se

Comment: @BenCottrell No AeLookupSvc is not running

Comment: @KurtCamilleri I'd suggest switching it on.   I disabled it once on my development PC, and this error drove me crazy for days until I figured out that was the cause, then re-enabled it again...

Comment: @BenCottrell how do I enable it since it is not visible in the services?

Comment: @HansPassant so what should I do?

Comment: @KurtCamilleri try `Start` -> `Run` -> type `services.msc` and find the `Application Experience` in the list, then right-click on it and click `Properties` to open the properties window for the service, then change the `Startup type` to `Automatic` and click the button to `Start` that service.

Comment: @BenCottrell I have application identity, application information and application layer gateway but no experience

Comment: @KurtCamilleri As far as I'm aware, it should be installed by default as part of Windows 10 - all I can find on the subject is this post from a Microsoft support engineer https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings-winpc/where-can-i-find-application-experience-service-in/a499361b-b7c5-46d1-81c3-15a098860446?auth=1

Comment: I still couldn't find it. Thanks for your help anyways. I will start a new project to check if the problem persists or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code solved my problem:

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Main main = new Main();
        this.Hide();
        main.ShowDialog();
        this.Close();
    }
```

The problem as some of the people that tried to help was that due to the this.Hide() the program was still being executed even though I pressed the close (x) button.

But now with the above code the form is closed and no background processes are running after the app is closed.